# Keras(Tensorflow) python clasification and analysis of image(root system)

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

Hey i have to build some kind of python image analysis software for a school project. The programs should be able to get a photo of a plant with its root system and classify and categorize the plants according to the size/thickness/angles/lenght of the roots.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EtQE.png)

I have installed Keras and Tensorflow, can i use it to e.g measure the lenghts of the roots? 
Is there an example of the usage of keras solving a "similar" problem.

Comment: you could use the iris dataset example to classify the roots, but not sure of measuring the lengths